# Python imaplib login failed

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I'm working on mail application and encountering a big problem with Python imaplib.

Here is the code that I try to use to login to mail server.

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4(self.server,int(self.port))
M.login(self.user, self.password)
```

I'm using `"port 143"`, `"useSLL = false"`, `no secure`. 
And here is the message that I receive when trying to login to server.

```
DEBUG:root:Login failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/IMAPmailbox/bin/get_imap_email.py", line 347, in getMail
    M.login(self.user, self.password)
  File "/opt/splunk/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 520, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
error: Login failed.
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/IMAPmailbox/bin/get_imap_email.py", line 724, in <module>
    parseArgs()
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/IMAPmailbox/bin/get_imap_email.py", line 716, in parseArgs
    imapProc.getMail()
  File "/opt/splunk/etc/apps/IMAPmailbox/bin/get_imap_email.py", line 352, in getMail
    raise LoginError('Could not log into server: %s with password provided' % self.server)
__main__.LoginError: Could not log into server: (my server) with password provided
```

p/s: I have another mail application which get emails throw imap on ruby and it's working fine with port 143 no secure. 
Anyone please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: It really does look like you're using the wrong server address, username or password. You could try tuning debugging on with `M.debug = 4` before the login call to get more detail.

Comment: I put my debug there and my server address, username and password are right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

`M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.server,int(self.port))
 M.login(self.user, self.password)`

I am using `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL` instead of `imaplib.IMAP4`and this seems to work for me

Comment: Please enhance your answer by explaining the difference between OP's code and yours. Why doesn't OP's code work while yours works?

Comment: done! 
P.S. I'm using SSL connectivity with IMAP and this works perfectly fine

Comment: OK, now your answer is safe from downvotes (from me at least). Want to get an upvote? Then go and research the reason why ´IMAP4_SSL` works and just `IMAP4` doesn't. Read the docs, cite the most relevant parts here.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution which work for both gmail and Outlook

def connect(self, username, password):
if self.tls:
self.server.starttls()

```
    if(self.hostname == 'imap.outlook.com'):
        imap_server = "outlook.office365.com"
        self.server = self.transport(imap_server, self.port)
        self.server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
        (retcode, capabilities) = self.server.login(username,password)
        self.server.select('inbox')
    else:
        typ, msg = self.server.login(username, password)
        if self.folder:
            self.server.select(self.folder)
        else:
            self.server.select()
```